# Browser Got Stuck during Jquery Execution. How to execute the Jquery smoothly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image-processing, html2canvas

I am working on T-Shirt Builder. I have about 34 Images in one Stuff and Gender. Like     T-Shirt > Men  have 34 Image to generate from div to Image using [html2Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) . It's working well with 7 or 8 Images but browser got stuck when execution goes for 34 images. I want to ask how I can make div to images conversation smoothly?
[image: T-Shirt Builder]

Here is my code that i used to convert the images:

var main_parent;
$(document).ready(function () {

```
$('.generate-all-images').click(function(e){



//     for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {

//         (function(i){

//             setTimeout(function() { alert('here') }, 5000);

//         })(i);

//    }


    var imgs=$(this).closest('.product-design-area').find('.product-Info-area').find('.all_stuffs_infos')
    $('.imgs-group-vals').html('')

    $.each(imgs, function (indexInArray, valueOfElement) {
        var p=$(this)
              setTimeout(function(){
                var i=p.find('.product-scroll-img ul li input').val()
                window.main_parent=p
                   $('#desing-img-replacer').attr('src',i)
                   convertImgs()
            }, 30000 * (indexInArray + 1));
    });

})


function convertImgs(){
        html2canvas($('.main-product-print-area')[0],{scrollY: -window.scrollY}).then(function (canvas) {
        var img=canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
        window.main_parent.find('.product-scroll-img ul li img').attr('src',img)
        var t=window.main_parent.find('.img_info_area .mockup_img').val(img)
        console.log(t)
    })


}
```

});

Further Issues I am facing that some images don't convert properly. Image got misplaces due to wrong time conversion.

Comment: Why are you multiplying the timeout?

Comment: Because in each loop SetTimeout don't work well.  All execution goes at once.

Comment: why do you need a timeout, why not just run it directly?

Comment: Because browser got stuck.  after 7 to 8 images conversion.

Comment: can you please also post the code you used before adding the timeout?

Comment: Please check the question. I edited it for you.

Comment: i meant, the code without a timeout (the code you used before)